# How to force AMD graphics on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, graphics-card, amd-radeon, intel-graphics, switchable-graphics

This is what I got from `windows graphics settings`

[image: https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HqdA0aA.png]

And this is my `device manager`

[image: https://cdn.pbrd.co/images/HqdADm0.png]

- My AMD graphic driver and Intel HD graphic driver are the *latest version*
- My laptop is `HP probook 4530s`
- Switchable graphics entry in BIOS is `on`
- I have `Catalyst_16.2.1_UnifL_v1.0` up and running *(no success)*
- I've reset my BIOS settings once *(no success)*
- I'd already tried drivers from `HP support` *(no success)*

need help :/

Comment: use the AMD driver settings to change the settings

Comment: So are you trying to change to AMD graphics then or what is your question? I see your specs and that's clear but what you are asking is not real clear without making assumptions.

Comment: @pimp-juice-it I want to force my pc to use the amd graphics preferably every where. Somehow I want to put the intel graphics away

Comment: @magicandre1981 I've changed every possible settings I found but no success

Comment: is this not working? https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/DH-017.aspx

Comment: I'm not familiar with this make a model laptop with the two GPU interfaces. I think you should look for the AMD GPU management tool installed onto the Windows OS as Mr. MagicAndre suggests as a starting point. Otherwise check BIOS/UEFI options for disabling the Intel/on-board or whatever.

Answer (score 1):

this is an old post, but there is a simple solution of your issue :

disable the Intel Integrated GPU in the Device Manager,
this will force Windows to use the AMD discrete GPU.

This work for all "static switchable graphic" like the AMD HD series, and this is the only solution, as Windows 10 only support "dynamic switchable graphic".

Answer (score 0):

I do have similar problem while I replacing my broken nvidia graphic card with an AMD one.
As @Pimp Juice IT suggests, you had to disable the on-board Intel graphics via BIOS/UEFI options (although it will cause real troubles when the standalone graphics card broken).
I am not sure BIOS/UEFI of my PC do have "Switchable graphics" options enabled at that time, it seems that it just not work for any graphic cards.